# Flask, carry a variable from @app.before_request to @app.route

Tags: python, flask

`@app.before_request` is executed before each request.
then it's `@app.route` (depending of your endpoint)

What would be the best to carry a variable from `@app.before_request` to `@app.route` and if possible without passing by a global variable.. is it possible ?

Thanks.

```py
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    x = 'anything'

@app.route('/')
def root():
    #would like to retrieve the value of x here...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way would be to add it to the g variable.

```py
from flask import g

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.my_variable = "This is a variable I want to pass"



@app.route('/')
def my_route():
    my_data = g.my_variable
    return f"Data from before_request: {my_data}"
```

Comment: from flask import Flask, g